# ARCore with Unreal - Create a NxN Meters plain

Tags: unreal-engine4, arcore

I'm very new to Unreal Engine and ARCore. But I need to create a "plain" with a NxN meters scaling. 
I want to build a city where I can walkthrough. All with ARCore.
Does anyone have a good tutorial or a good hint for this?

Answer (score 0):

Good Documentation  For AR Core  With Unreal Engine

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unreal/quickstart

Comment: Should be a comment.